# Fetching picture from folder in PHP Docker

Tags: php, docker, apache, ubuntu

In my PHP application i am using docker on my ubuntu machine. Previously it was working perfectly but now its not. I am trying to show image from my uplaoded folder. The link showing the the image src is correct.Plus file also exist in folder but the image is not showing . When i try to access image directly from browser URL  its saying

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80
```

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM php:7.3.28-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

RUN chown -R www-data /var/*
RUN chown -R 777 /var/*

RUN a2enmod rewrite
EXPOSE 80
```

everything is working fine but only the image is not coming in my browser.

[image]

You can see in the above pic image src is there but its showing blank and image is exist in the folder.Also i tried to change the permission to 777 but didnt worked.

sudo chmod -R 777 uploads

[image][image]

Docker Compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    container_name: php_medix_uk
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
      - ./config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: "always"
  # MySQL
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0.25
    container_name: mysql_host
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: medix_pharma
      MYSQL_USER: medix_pharma
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: medix_pharma
    volumes:
      - ~/mysql/medix_uk:/var/lib/mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
    - 3306:3306

  # phpMyAdmin
  phpmyadmin:
   # container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    - PMA_HOSTS=mysql_host
    - PMA_USER=root
    - PMA_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
    - 8080:80
    depends_on:
    - db
```

inside ./config/vhosts directory i have default.conf file

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you link your volumes ?

Comment: Yes i do in docker-compose file

Comment: Chowning the entirety of `/var` is a bad idea, and the second one looks like it should be `chmod` instead, which is also a doubly-bad idea.

Comment: Yes but its in development mode

Comment: Can you provide your docker compose file ?

Comment: Yes sure see above i added that too thanks